# check regex for integers bigger than the negative -328

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm looking for a regex that is able to match numbers bigger than -328, and if it is possible to provide another solution to match the same pattern but without the zero. I tried many things but still not sure about how it works, for example, `^\-?[0-9]\d{3,}$` 
I'm using it with the `com.jfoenix.validation.RegexValidator` in order to check the pattern in a textfield.

Thanks

Comment: Regular expressions are the worst possible tools for range checking. You should convert the text to an integer and range-check it with the comparison operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
String pat = "^-(32[0-7]|3[0-1]\\d|[1-2]\\d\\d|\\d{1,2})|\\d+$";
for (int i = -1000; i <= 1000; ++i) {
    String s = Integer.toString(i);
    boolean result = s.matches(pat);
    if (result != (i > -328))
        System.out.println(i + " fail!");
}
```

Comment: bro this is perfect, you just saved my programming project